# How to minimise computation time for a matrix diagonalisation plotting script in matlab?

Tags: matlab

I am fairly new to matlab and was hoping for some assistance regarding the speeding up of computation and plotting of eigenvalues. I have a 'pentadiagonal' 40x40 matrix, with symbolic k entries.

I wish to compute all of the eigenvalues and plot these as a function of k. So I call eig(H), then I set up a loop which replaces the symbolic k entries with a numerical value. I then simply plot this array, which I have called 'list'.

This routine takes a long time to evaluate, and I do need all of the eigenvalues rather than just the n largest. Does anybody have any advice as to how I can speed up this calculation?

Things I have tried:
1) Preallocating my array. This didn't appear to speed it up much. I believe at this stage, the code still holds the eigenvalues as Root[#1^2+cos(1.0*3)...] objects, and the list is relatively small.

2) Rescaling the arguments of the trig functions cos((sqrt(3)/2)*k) -> cos(k). This also doesn't appear to speed it up a huge amount.

I would be very grateful for any further advice.

```
a=0.5;
b=0.5;
dq=0.01;
d=0.5;
syms k 
H= [(-2)*a - b*d*sin(sqrt(3)*k), 2*a*cos((sqrt(3)/2)*k), b*d*sin((sqrt(3)/2)*k), 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0,0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0; 2*a*cos((sqrt(3)/2)*k), -1, ...]


list = [];
for s=0:dq:3
    list=[list,subs(energies,k,s)];
end
q=0:dq:3;
plot(q,transpose(list),'red')
```

Comment: `list = []` is not preallocating. Where is `dq` defined?

Comment: If you truly want to speed this up - don't use symbolics! If you want `H` to be a function of `k`, define it as such: e.g. `function out = H(k) ...` or, if you can fit this in one line, `H = @(k)[(-2)*a ...`. Also, it might be possible to avoid the loop entirely if vectorization is applicable (which it should be, to some extent).

Comment: Yeah I know that list =[]  is not a preallocated list. The version of this code that I ran with a preallocated list i.e. list =zeros(n) showed no noticeable improvement in computation time. dq is some constant step size for the list. I've added the definition to the code, apologies for the lack of clarity.

Thank you, for the advice Dev-iL , I'll try running with H defined as a function. A cursory reading about vectorization suggests may be applicable. I'll give it a go!